# WebSocketChannel stream returns a Bad state: stream has already been listened to error even if I set it to be a broadcast stream

Tags: flutter, websocket, stream-builder

I recently added a feature in my app to logout. When I press the button to logout I Navigate back to  the LoginScreen and display a username and password prompt.
I know the WebSocketChannel channel.stream can't be listened to more than once, so I created a broadcast stream and set it to the channel.stream.
Here is my initState() and dispose() code:

```
  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    _hasToken();
    broadcastStream = channel.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

And here is my LoginScreen build method and the widgets:

```
  List<Widget> getLoginScreen()
  {
    List<Widget> kids = [];

    if(hereAuthenticated == 0)
    {
      kids.add(new Container
      (
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration
        (
          gradient: LinearGradient
          (
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors:
            [
              Color(0xFF73AEF5),
              Color(0xFF61A4F1),
              Color(0xFF478DE0),
              Color(0xFF398AE5),
            ],
            stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    if(hereAuthenticated == 0)
    {
      kids.add(new Container
      (
        height: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView
        (
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric
          (
            horizontal: 40.0,
            vertical: 120.0,
          ),
          child: Column
          (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>
            [
              Text('XXXX',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'OpenSans',fontSize: 30.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),
              SizedBox(height: 30.0),
              _buildEmailTF(),
              SizedBox(height: 30.0,),
              _buildPasswordTF(),
              _buildForgotPasswordBtn(),
              _buildLoginBtn(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    if(hereAuthenticated == 2)
    {
      kids.add(Container
      (
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.blue,)
      ));
    }
    
    kids.add(new StreamBuilder
    (
      stream: broadcastStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot)
      {
        if(snapshot.hasData)
        {
          String rawJson = snapshot.data;
          Map<String, dynamic> inputMap = jsonDecode(rawJson);
          print('RAWJSON: $rawJson');
          if(hereAuthenticated == 0)
          {
            if(inputMap['type'] == 'auth_response') hereAuthenticated = inputMap['access'];
            if(inputMap.containsKey('token')) storage.write(key: 'xxxx', value: inputMap['token']);
          }
          else if(hereAuthenticated == 2)
          {
            if(inputMap['type'] == 'auth_response') hereAuthenticated = inputMap['access'];
            if(inputMap.containsKey('token'))
            {
              storage.delete(key: 'xxxx');
              storage.write(key: 'xxxx', value: inputMap['token']);
            }
          }
        }
        if(hereAuthenticated == 1)
        {
          return(StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
            stream: FlutterBlue.instance.state,
            initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
            builder: (c, snapshot) 
            {
              final state = snapshot.data;
              if (state == BluetoothState.on) return FindDevicesScreen();
              return BluetoothOffScreen(state: state);
            }
          ));
        }
        else return(Text(''));
      },
    ));
    return kids;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold
    (
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Stack(
            children: getLoginScreen(),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: DId you get the solution ?